# Using regex in tag "watching & Ignored Tags"

Tags: support, tags

Under *Edit profile and settings* → *Tag watching & ignoring*, I am using a glob pattern to add tags in both **Tag Watching** & **Ignored Tags**.

The problem is, `ruby*` includes -

```
ruby
ruby-on-rails
ruby-on-rails-3
ruby-on-rails-4
ruby-on-rails-5
rubygems
```

Now I want to only watch `rubygems` and ignore rest of the five tags.

How do I do it?

Will it work if I add `ruby*` under **Ignored Tags**, and add `rubygems` under **Tag Watching**?

Comment: Why not remove `ruby*` and just add `rubygems`?

Comment: I want to clearly define what I want and what I don't want. There are other use cases as well.

Comment: The * is the only glob pattern that works. There is no regex here and don't expect it ever will.

Comment: @rene I changed regex to glob pattern in the question.